# Question about two definitions of Teichmuller space for a surface of genus $g$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmueller-theory

There are many equivalent definitions of Teichmuller space for a surface of genus $g\ge 2$.

One of them concerns the complex structure: the Teichmuller space $\mathcal{T}(g)$ is the set of the couples $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$ and $f:S\rightarrow X$ is the marking, i.e. an orientation preserving diffeomorphism up to the equivalence $(X,f)\sim(X',f')$ iff there is a biholomorphism homotopic to $f'\circ f^{-1}$.

Another definition concerns the hyperbolic structure: $\mathcal{T}(g)$ is the set of the couples $(Y,h)$ there $Y$ is a hyperbolic surface of genus $g$ and $h:S\rightarrow Y$ is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism up to the equivalence $(Y,h)\sim(Y',h')$ iff there is an isometry homotopic to $h'\circ h^{-1}$.

My question is: how are these two definitions equivalent? How can I explicitly obtain the complex structure from the hyperbolic one and vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obtaining a complex structure from a hyperbolic structure is quite easy.  The hyperbolic plane (using either the Poincare disk or upper half plane model) can be viewed as a subset of the complex plane, and orientation-preserving hyperbolic isometries are biholomorphic.  Thus any atlas of orientation-preserving hyperbolic charts on an oriented hyperbolic surface can also be viewed as an atlas of complex charts, so any oriented hyperbolic surface is automatically a complex surface.

The reverse direction is a little bit harder.  If $X$ is a Riemann surface (i.e. a surface with a complex structure), then the universal cover $\widetilde{X}$ of $X$ must be a simply connected Riemann surface.  According to the [Uniformization Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem), the only simply connected Riemann surfaces are the Riemann sphere, the complex plane, and the unit disk.  For a surface of $g>=2$, the universal cover must be the unit disk. Then the deck transformations of the cover must be biholomorphisms of the unit disk, and those are precisely the orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane under the Poincare disk model.   It is now easy to give $X$ an atlas of hyperbolic charts consisting of lifts of evenly covered neighborhoods of $X$ to the universal cover.

The key point here is that a properly discontinuous group of biholomorphisms of the unit disk is exactly the same thing as a properly discontinuous group of orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane, and thus the quotients are the same.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more question: where can I find the proof of what you call the "key point", i.e. that the deck transformations are exactly the isometries for the hyperbolic metric?

Comment: @user61720 Well, the biholomorphisms of the unit disk are just the Mobius transformations that send the unit disk to iself.  This follows from the Schwarz Lemma and/or the Schwarz-Pick Theorem, which can be found in most complex analysis books. These Mobius transformations are also precisely the orientation-preserving isometries of the hyperbolic plane, a theorem that can be found in just about any treatment of hyperbolic geometry. (Note that, when you look at references, some of them might use the upper half plane instead of the unit disk, but this is the same thing.)